# varpart function of vegan package in R detecting unexpected collinearity between factor and numeric variable

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to run variation partitioning analysis on some response data. I have three constraining variables, one numeric variable and two factors, which are dummy variables that I am encoding to intentionally capture variation associated with predicted signals in the response data. The issue I have is that the `varpart()` function is detecting collinearity between one of the factor variables and the numeric variable. I believe this is because the numeric variable is encoded as discrete values, and the 'jumps' between these values correspond to jumps between different factor levels.

Here is an example of the two variables in question:

```r
var1 <- unlist(lapply(1:5, function(x){rep(x, 20)}))
var1
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
# [44] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
# [87] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5

var2 <- as.factor(unlist(lapply(letters[1:5], FUN = function(x){rep(x, 20)})))
var2
# [1] a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b b c c c
# [44] c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d d e e e e e e
# [87] e e e e e e e e e e e e e e
# Levels: a b c d e
```

Above, `var1` is meant to capture variation in a predicted gradient in the response data which changes after every 20 units. For example, as coded above, this may represent a linear arrangement of 5 sites, with a sample of 20 draw from each. In contrast, `var2` is meant to capture variation that is unique to each site, thus it is represented as a factor with a different level for each of the 5 sites, again changing every 20 units.

(I also have a separate variable which by design is not correlated with either of these: `var3 <- as.factor(rep(c(rep("type1", 10), rep("type2", 10)), 5))`)

Here are some sample response data:

```r
response <- sapply(1:100, function(x){x <- rbinom(100, 2, .5)})
> response[1:5, 1:5]
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    2    1    2
[3,]    2    1    1    1    0
[4,]    1    0    2    1    1
[5,]    2    1    1    0    1
```

When executing `varpart(response, var1, var2, var3)`, I get the following warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: collinearity detected in cbind(X1,X2): mm = 5, m = 4 
2: collinearity detected in cbind(X1,X2,X3): mm = 6, m = 5 
3: collinearity detected: redundant variable(s)  between tables X1, X2
results are probably incorrect: remove redundant variable(s) and repeat the analysis 
4: collinearity detected: redundant variable(s)  between tables X1, X2, X3
results are probably incorrect: remove redundant variable(s) and repeat the analysis
```

Moreover, the individual contribution of var1 to total variation is exactly zero, which is unexpected (albeit these are simulated data).

Why is this collinearity appearing between the factor and the numeric variable? Can `varpart` not handle this design?

Answer (score 3):

See what you get from

```
table(var1, var2)
```

Your two variables (`var1` and `var2` are identical) – only coded in different ways (numbers, letters). `varpart` really can handle this design, and it finds that nothing can be done if you want decompose your variation into two identical parts.